# Finding the volume under the plane x+y+z = 1

Tags: calculus, geometry

My two methods are giving me different answers, and I'm not sure why.

I am more confident in: $\int_0^1\int_0^{1-x}\int_0^{1-x-y}dz~dy~dx = \frac16$.

But another way I'm trying is to sum the area of all the equilateral triangles underneath, and parallel to, the plane. The side lengths of these triangles range from $0$ to $\sqrt2$.

Thus: $\int_0^{\sqrt2}s^2\frac{\sqrt3}{4}~ds = \frac{1}{\sqrt6}$.

I am pretty sure the second approach is incorrect, but why?

EDIT: We are given $x,y,z>0$.

Comment: What is the plane bounded by?

Comment: The positive octant.

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to do what is sometimes called "volume-by-slicing". This is where you integrate the cross-sectional areas of the region to calculate the volume. When you do this, though, the cross-sections should be **perpendicular** to the "axis of integration". What I mean is that in your integral, $s$ (the side length of the equilateral triangles) should not be the parameter. Instead, the parameter (let's call it $t$) should represent the distance from the cross-section to the origin.

The line normal to the plane $z=1-x-y$ is in the direction of the vector $\left<1,1,1\right>$, so it's not hard to check that the intersection of this line with the plane is $\frac{1}{3} \left<1,1,1\right>$, which is a distance of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$ from the origin. So our $t$ parameter should go from $0$ to $\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$. Then $s$, the length of the edge of the cross-sectional equilateral triangles, can be expressed in terms of $t$ as $s = \sqrt{3} \sqrt{2} \, t$, or as $s = \sqrt{6} \, t$.

Now if you compute the integral

$$ \int_0^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}} \frac{\sqrt{3}}{4} \cdot 6 t^2 dt $$

you will get $\frac{1}{6}$, which agrees with your other calculation.

Comment: Great explanation. Thank you very much!